# Nullpointer exception during object creation

Tags: java

I am writing a stack program in Java.
In the code the push function is causing a null pointer exception.
I guess the node is not getting created. Please advice.
Thanks in advance

```
//Stack_using_ll is a stack implementation using linked list 
public class Stack_using_ll{
    private Node first;
    private int count;
    private class Node {
        private String str;
        private Node next;
    }// Node has a value and reference

    public void push(String item){
        Node old_first = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.str = item;
        first.next = old_first.next;
        //first = node;
        count++;
    }//Inserts a new node
    public String pop(){
        String str_pop = first.str;
        first = first.next;
        count--;
        return str_pop;
    }//pops the string out of the stack
    public boolean is_empty(){
        if(first == null)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }//check if the stack is empty

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Stack_using_ll stack = new Stack_using_ll() ;
        stack.push("Jeans");
        System.out.println("There are " + stack.count + " elements in stack");
    }
}//End of class Stack_using_ll
```

-------------The output i get is as follows-----------------------------

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Stack_using_ll$Node.access$2(Stack_using_ll.java:7)
    at Stack_using_ll.push(Stack_using_ll.java:14)
    at Stack_using_ll.main(Stack_using_ll.java:33)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

Comment: You can just use LinkedList for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within your main method you create a new Stack_using_ll object, this creates any member variables, however you never give `first` a value (e.g. within the constructor), as such it remains null.

```
private Node first; //<--- first is null here and you use the blank constructor, so it is never given a non null value
```

You then call `stack.push("Jeans");` in your main method which attempts to use `first`, but `first` is null, hence the exception.

```
public void push(String item){
    Node old_first = first; //<-- the initial null is preserved here
    first = new Node();
    first.str = item;
    first.next = old_first.next; //<-- you attempt to use the preserved null here
    //first = node;
    count++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code:

```
public class Stack_using_ll{
    private Node first;
```

`private Node first` only declares a reference to a Node named 'first', it does not create an instance of a Node for it to refer to.

So, when you later assign `first` to `oldFirst`, you're assigning a `null`, attempting to access a member of a null results in a NPE

```
public void push(String item){
        Node old_first = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.str = item;
        first.next = old_first.next; <- NPE here
```

Answer (score 0):

`first` is null at the beginning so when you do: `old_first = first`, old_first becomes null, so `old_first.next` gives you **exception**.

**Solution:**

```
 public void push(String item){
        Node old_first = first;
        first = new Node();
        first.str = item;
        if(old_first!=null)
           first.next = old_first.next;
    ...}
```

Answer (score 0):

problem is the null pointer in the first time you push to you object (because first item is null and you try to get its .next

see correction below : (in push function )

```
public void push(String item){
    Node old_first = first;
    first = new Node();
    first.str = item;
    //first time old_first is null!
    if (old_first != null){
       first.next = old_first.next;
    }
    //first = node;
    count++;
}
```